# Why Gaudiya Vaishnavas chant the Mahamantra from oppsite direction?

Tags: mantras, upanishads, gaudiya-vaishnavism, iskcon

Gaudiya Vaishnavas consider the following 16-word mantra as the Mahamantra and always chant it.

> Hare Krishna Hare Krishna
> Krishna Krishna Hare Hare
> Hare Rama Hare Rama
> Rama Rama Hare Hare

This mantra is mentioned in the very beginning of the Kali Santarana Upanishad (verse 2), a minor Upanishad. However, there the Mantra is mentioned as the following -

> Hare Rama Hare Rama
> Rama Rama Hare Hare
> Hare Krishna Hare Krishna
> Krishna Krishna Hare Hare

> नारदः पुनः पप्रच्छ तन्नाम किमिति। स होवाच हिरण्यगर्भः। **हरे राम हरे राम राम राम हरे हरे। हरे कृष्ण हरे कृष्ण कृष्ण कृष्ण हरे हरे।** इति षोडशकं नाम्नां कलिकल्मषनाशनम्।

Very strange. Why do they chant it from the opposite direction?

Reference -

- 30 Minor Upanishads translated by K. Narayanswami Iyar
- 112 Upanishads translated by K L Joshi

Comment: It was the mantra given as initiation to Chaitanya Mahaprabhu that was *inspired* via Kali Santarana Upanishat. When chanting it in a sequence, the mantra automatically coincides with the original mantra. Since they are pro-Krishna sect, they keep Krishna first without any harm to original mantra via sequential chanting.

Comment: @User29449 You simply cannot change the sequence of a Mantra, which is part of Sruti - revealed scripture!

Comment: @User29449 You can say it is a new mantra, which has no scriptural basis. That is fine. You can chant whatever you like. But you cannot just get "inspired" by the scripture and then change the scripture.

Comment: It is not changing, it is a custom guru mantra (mantra diksha) to Chaitanya Mahaprabhu. It definitely does not has any scriptural basis, but Krishnites keep Krishna foremost and chant in that way. Repeated japa automatically leads to correction.

Comment: @User29449 If the creator Brahma himself put Rama before Krishna, then I do not think anybody has the right to change the sequence. If they do, they have to come up with a solid theological justification.

Comment: This I don't really know. Personally, Gaudiyas reject **most** number of scriptures (including shrutis) with smriti justification from what I've seen. So I cannot comment on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the present Shankaracharya of Puri Govardhan Math, Swami Nischalananda Saraswati ji has said in one of his videos the order was reversed so that women and Shudras could be initiated into it.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=2OvJhGktw8g

Comment: That is a good theological justification.

Comment: However I'm not sure if this is what the sringeri acharya thinks since there is a video of him making the audience(consisting of people of multiple castes) chant the mantra with hare rama at the beginning @AmritenduMukhopadhyay

Comment: Thanks for raising an important point. If possible please add the video link. However, at least, one Shankaracharya (of Puri) thinks the above way. That itself made it an authoritative explanation.

Comment: Here https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=uphe_8bm3NA @AmritenduMukhopadhyay

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).